# segmentation fault error in linked list function in C

Tags: c, function, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a linked list of nodes, that all have an employee struct pointer inside of them. I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to add a new node to the end. Below is my function to add a node to the end of the list.

```
    void addToEnd(node_t **head, employee_t *employee){
        node_t *current_node = *head;
        while(current_node->next != NULL){
            current_node = current_node->next;
        }
        current_node->next = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        current_node->next->empInfo = employee;
        current_node->next->next = NULL;
    }
```

Here is the code I am passing into the function:

```
     int main (void) {

        setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
        setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

         employee_t *empPtr1, emp1,*empPtr2, emp2;
         empPtr1 = &emp1;
         empPtr2 = &emp2;

         node_t head;
         head.next = NULL:
         node_t *headPtr;
         node_t **headPtr2;
         headPtr2 = &headPtr;
         headPtr = &head;

         emp1.firstName = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
         emp1.lastName = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

         emp2.firstName = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
         emp2.lastName = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

             printf("Please enter the first name of the first employee you'd like to add:");
             scanf("%s", empPtr1->firstName);
             printf("Please enter the last name of the first employee you'd like to add:");
             scanf("%s", empPtr1->lastName);


             printf("Please enter the first name of the second employee you'd like to add:");
             scanf("%s", empPtr2->firstName);
             printf("Please enter the last name of the second employee you'd like to add:");
             scanf("%s", empPtr2->lastName);

             addToEnd(headPtr2, empPtr1);
             addToEnd(headPtr2, empPtr2);
    ...
```

If anyone has any idea why the function is giving me a seg fault it would be much appreciated, as I have looked through many threads on here and found nothing similar.

Comment: Which statement is getting the segmentation fault?

Comment: If your names are more than 9 characters, you will explode.  Consider limiting scanf input to protect you.

Comment: Knowing what `employee_t` is will help to know if something is wrong there.  Knowing what line it is crashing on in a debugger would help a lot too.  Also, enable warnings to see if the compiler sees an issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you create `head`, you need to initialize its `next` pointer to `NULL`:

```
node_t head;
head.next = NULL;
```

Otherwise, the loop in `addToEnd()` will not know when it has reached the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you! unfortunately even when I do that I still get a seg fault.

Comment: I asked above what line the seg fault is happening on. Running the program in a debugger should help you figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `main`, make sure `headPtr` points to NULL before the 2 function calls to 
 `addToEnd`:

```
 node_t * headPtr=NULL; //just keep this pointer for head, no other needed.
 ...
 // Few lines later ..
 addToEnd(&headPtr, empPtr1);
 addToEnd(&headPtr, empPtr2);
```

Whenever using pointer initialize it with `NULL`. So, now you need to take care of 2 situations in your `addToEnd` function: when `headPtr` is `NULL` and not `NULL`. Also, you need to check everytime when you are dereferencing any pointer that whether its `NULL` or not.

Change your `addToEnd` function to this:

```
void addToEnd(node_t **head, employee_t *employee){
        node_t current_node = *head;

        node_t *temp = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        temp->empInfo = employee;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if (*head == NULL){  //For the first case when the list will be empty 
            *head = temp;
            return;
        }     

        while (current_node->next != NULL){       
               current_node=current_node->next;
        }
        current_node->next = temp;
        return;
    }
```